# Creating a Dask dataframe from database cursor

Tags: dataframe, dask

I have a cursor for retrieving data from a database.
After executing a query I would usually store it in a pandas dataframe using `fetchall()`.

Once the data gets too large for memory, this method no longer works.

I am thinking of using dask to store the results for further analysis. Being quite new to dask, I was wondering what was the best way to go about this.

eg.

```
query = """SELECT * FROM table"""
cursor.execute(query)

# Would usually do something like
df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in cursor.fetchall()])
```

Answer (score 3):

The `cursor` object is not ideal for this kind of thing, because it has a single connection session and state, and so you can't meaningfully share it between threads or processes, only iterate over it (as you do in the comprehension).

Dask does have [`read_sql_table`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table) for this kind of job, which as the name suggests, is meant for loading from tables rather than generalised queries.

You may also be interested in [intake-sql](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/intake-sql), which includes plugins for both the above function, and for a general query where you know beforehand how to for the WHERE statements to make partitions. This is in the context of the [Intake](https://intake.readthedocs.io/) project, which allows you to encode your data loading specification into data source catalogues.